# How to properly override a method in typescript?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, this

Why is `this.fullName` empty in `show()` method?

```
class Person {
  protected name: string = "";
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.makeSir(name);
  }

  makeSir(name: string) {
    this.name = "sir" + name;  
  }
}

class Man extends Person {
  protected fullName = "";
  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }

  makeSir(name: string) {
    super.makeSir(name);
    this.fullName = "***" + name;
    console.log(this.fullName);//[LOG]: "***john" 
  }

  show() {
    console.log(this.fullName);//[LOG]: "" 
  }
}


const man = new Man("john");
man.show();
```

How should I fix this?

Comment: Please elaborate which language, the output

Comment: I had specified the language in the tags. And the output had been commented in the code. @ArfatBinkileb

Comment: My take on this is that you can't change children's property in the super call since by the time of super, the children's properties don't exist yet.

Comment: So basically the initialization of `fullName` happens after `super` call, which overrides the `fullName` you set up in `makeSir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`super()` is *always* the first thing called when constructing a derived class like your `Man`. This includes being *before* any variable initialization you do, such as `protected fullName = ''`. Therefore, while your `Man.makeSir` is being called and setting `fullName` to a good value, right afterwards your empty string assignment kicks in and clears its value.

One way to avoid this late overwrite is to not set an initial value for `fullName`:

```
// give it a type because we don't give it an initial value
// use `!` syntax to hint to TypeScript that this will be initialized during the constructor
// even though TS cannot figure that out itself
protected fullName!: string;
```

Now since you never set `fullName` to an "initial" value, you never overwrite the work done by the `super()` call.

Comment: This is really interesting!  I would not have thought that variable initialization would happen *after* the constructor calls `makeSir`.  But when I think about it more it does make sense because it's being triggered by `super()`.

Comment: When I consider the prototypal nature of how JS handles objects this makes sense, but IMO it’s still frustrating if you come from other OOP languages like C# or Java.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person  {
    
protected name: String ="";
    
    constructor(name: string){
        this.makeSir(name);
    }
    
    makeSir(name: string){
        this.name="sir"+name ;
    }
    
    test(){
        console.log("PERSON");
    }
}

class Man extends Person {
    public name: string ="";
    
    constructor(name:string){
        super(name);
        this.makeSir(name);
    }
    
    makeSir(name:string){
        this.name="####"+name;
    }
    
    test(){
        console.log("Man ")
    }
    show(){
        console.log("#####"+this.name);
    }
}

const n = new Man("Man ")
n.show();
n.test();


const m = new Person("Person");
m.test();
```

Your are only calling `super` in constructor, which in tern calls super constructor only.

If you see test is overridden properly

Output:

```
#########Man 
Man 
PERSON
```